# Pine Script v5 compiler report "undeclared identifier"

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

code like this:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

x = if open > close
    var a = 10
    var b = 20
    a := 20
    b := 30
    (a+b)[1]
plot(x)
```

**compiler report "a" and "b" in (a+b)[1] are undeclared identifiers:**

```
line 11: Undeclared identifier 'a';
line 11: Undeclared identifier 'b'
```

but 'a' and 'b' are declared in the block
if modify expr '(a+b)[1]' to 'a+b', the compilation is successful. how the compiler works？

Answer (score 0):

In my case, compiler reports the issue specifically with the `a` on the 11th line (in the `else` branch). In this case, the error is expected because the `a` variable was declared inside the `if` branch and does not exist in the `else` branch at all.

For this to work, you need to declare a outside of the `if/else` condition. Here's one possible way to rewrite this code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

f() =>
    var a = 10
    var b = 20
    if open > close
        a := 20
        b := 30
        (a+b)[1]
    else
        a
x = f()
    
plot(x)
```

Comment: delete "else a", i update my code in my question, it report "line11 undeclared identifier a, b", i want to know why 'a' and 'b' are both in scope, but compiler report 'undeclared identifier error'

Comment: This looks like a bug. I've reported it to the Pine team.

Comment: Please let me know if you get a reply from pine team,thanks

Comment: They say it is a bug and they'll investigate it. For the time being, I suggest using `(a[1]+b[1])` as recommended below.

Answer (score 0):

Very often, the compiler message does not exactly match the problem,
you have to guess what it is trying to say.

In this case and logically, the declarations should not be in an "if" section because the variables are accessible everywhere in the script,
so you must declare them at the lowest level.